# Mongo Script to transform data

Tags: mongodb

We have a document that needs to be transformed into a different structure document and to be saved in a different mongo database.
How can I do that?

This must be done via a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct new documents based on old ones by the use of **field references**. We can use literals like `$mergeObjects`.

```
{
"newfield1" "$oldDocField1"
"newfield2" "$oldDocField2"
{
"newfield3" "$oldDocField3"
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).